# Generate Random Symmetric positive definite matrix

Tags: matrix, random

Is there any way to create a random symmetric positive definite matrix ?

Comment: Define "random."

Comment: @David G. Stork sir, thanks for the reply,actually i  want to create a positive definite matrix randomly in  the range from (-1 ,1)

Comment: @revanthroy That does not define "random". You have to specify a probability distribution.

Answer (score 4):

See [a-simple-algorithm-for-generating-positive-semidefinite-matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619335/a-simple-algorithm-for-generating-positive-semidefinite-matrices)

Translation to Mathematica:

```
n    = 5; (*size of matrix, change as needed*)
q    = Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}], {n}, {n}];
mat  = Transpose[q].q;
PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ[mat]
(*true*)
```

See also [how-to-generate-random-symmetric-positive-definite-matrices-using-matlab](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357980/how-to-generate-random-symmetric-positive-definite-matrices-using-matlab)

> The matrix symmetric positive definite matrix A can be written as , A
>   = Q'DQ , where Q is a random matrix and D is a diagonal matrix with positive diagonal elements. The elements of Q and D can be randomly
>   chosen to make a random A.

Here is the translation of the code to Mathematica

```
n         = 5; (*size of matrix. Change as needed *)
q         = Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}], {n}, {n}];
eigenMean = 2; (*see link above *)

mat = Transpose[q].DiagonalMatrix[eigenMean + Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}], {n}]].q;

PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ[mat]
(*true*)
```

Comment: The first example works fine for a random positive semi-definite matrix, and it is already a symmetric matrix. I don't understand the advantage of the second example. Small additional comment: If the purpose is to generate a random positive **semi-definite** matrix, the test should be with the function `PositiveSemidefiniteMatrixQ`.

Answer (score 4):

```
dim = 10;

RandomVariate[GaussianOrthogonalMatrixDistribution[dim]]
```

or

```
With[{U = RandomVariate[CircularRealMatrixDistribution[dim]]},
 U.(RandomReal[{-1, 1}, dim] U\[Transpose])
 ]
```

Comment: Since OP did not specify a precise probability distribution, this question cannot be answered precisely.

Comment: Looks like the first option does not produce an SPD matrix. Try ```SeedRandom[0];
dim = 2;
m = RandomVariate[GaussianOrthogonalMatrixDistribution[dim]];
Eigenvalues[m]```with output `{-1.21836, -0.0868584}`. Both eigenvalues are negative.